# php: SimpleXML Load File Invalid Character Error

Tags: php, character, simplexml

I have a php application which -sometimes- fails (depends on what data I load) and gives errors like:

```
parser error : PCDATA invalid Char value 11
Warning: simplexml_load_file(): ath>/datadrivenbestpractices/Data-driven Best Practices in 
Warning: simplexml_load_file(): ^ in
```

I am certain that there are some values which are causing the problem. I don't have control over data. I have tried solutions from: [Error: "Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !" using PHP's simplexml_load_string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507608/error-input-is-not-proper-utf-8-indicate-encoding-using-phps-simplexml-lo) and [How to handle invalid unicode with simplexml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7766455/how-to-handle-invalid-unicode-with-simplexml) and [How to skip invalid characters in XML file using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466035/how-to-skip-invalid-characters-in-xml-file-using-php) but they have not helped.

The culprit strings are: 'Data Driven - Best Practices' and 'Data-driven Best Practices to Recruit and Retain Underrepresented Graduate Students May 12, 2011 - 1:30-3:00 p.m., EST' (may be dashes or return characters).

What can I do? Mine is a Windows php test environment but the live environment will be a LAMP one--can 't touch the .ini files.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you should show your XML source too.

Answer (score 18):

Stripping the invalid chars before parsing would be the easiest fix:

```php
function utf8_for_xml($string)
{
    return preg_replace ('/[^\x{0009}\x{000a}\x{000d}\x{0020}-\x{D7FF}\x{E000}-\x{FFFD}]+/u', ' ', $string);
}
```

From: [PHP generated XML shows invalid Char value 27 message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12229572/php-generated-xml-shows-invalid-char-value-27-message)

Comment: Not sure how this will work in my code: Here is how I load the xml: $xml_apicheck = simplexml_load_file($serveraddress.$myparam)

Comment: It should work if you do something like: `simplexml_load_string(utf8_for_xml(file_get_contents($serveraddress.$myparam)));`

Comment: okay, I have this: $xml_apicheck = simplexml_load_file(utf8_for_xml(file_get_contents($serveraddress.$myparam))); but am now getting error: action.php on line 100 PHP Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in

Comment: Problem may be that file_get_contents is not xml anymore?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, the answer in: [How to skip invalid characters in XML file using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466035/how-to-skip-invalid-characters-in-xml-file-using-php)
did work. Here is my code:

```
stream_filter_register('xmlutf8', 'ValidUTF8XMLFilter');

class ValidUTF8XMLFilter extends php_user_filter
{
    protected static $pattern = '/[^\x{0009}\x{000a}\x{000d}\x{0020}-\x{D7FF}\x{E000}-\x{FFFD}]+/u';

    function filter($in, $out, &$consumed, $closing)
    {
        while ($bucket = stream_bucket_make_writeable($in)) {
            $bucket->data = preg_replace(self::$pattern, '', $bucket->data);
            $consumed += $bucket->datalen;
            stream_bucket_append($out, $bucket);
        }
        return PSFS_PASS_ON;
    }
}

$doc = simplexml_load_file("php://filter/read=xmlutf8/resource=".$serveraddress.$myparam);
```