# php remove invalid chars

Tags: php, regex, dom, character

I have the following errors outputed when I work with `$dom->loadHTML('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' . $html);`.

```
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: Char 0xD860 out of allowed range in Entity, line: 1 in D:\xampp\xampp\htdocs\xampp\similarity\functions.php on line 438
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: Char 0xDEE2 out of allowed range in Entity, line: 1 in D:\xampp\xampp\htdocs\xampp\similarity\functions.php on line 438
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: Invalid char in CDATA 0x3 in Entity, line: 1 in D:\xampp\xampp\htdocs\xampp\similarity\functions.php on line 438
```

How do I target and remove those "invalid" charaters using php?

Andrej

Comment: You may need to consider a custom function to filter/translate invalid char. [http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1615290](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1615290)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466035/how-to-skip-invalid-characters-in-xml-file-using-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not tested, but this should work:

```
$buffer = ob_get_clean();
$tidy = new tidy();
$myHTML = $tidy->repairString('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' . $html);

$dom->loadHTML($myHTML);
```