# Malformed XML Cleanup - Data not in tags

Tags: php, xml, malformed

So I have XML with perfectly nested tags, however I'm ending up with weird characters directly outside of tags, such as:

```
<root><a_tag>Some perfectly valid string</a_tag> this
<b_tag>more data</b_tag>  
<c_tag>some more data</c_tag> 0</root>
```

Is there a function in PHP that does this natively, or will I need a regex to accomplish it?

Only function I'm already running on is from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3466049

Edit: When opening the file with emacs, the end of each line has a set of characters such as: ^@ or ^@S

Also - these documents were generated with InDesign.

Thanks!

Comment: When you say ended up, what would you have started with to produce the above.

Comment: There were various characters that were out of range, that the stripInvalidXml function removed.

Comment: Well looks like it got a bit greedy and wiped out some tags as well, or the xml you started with exhibited similar legal but hard to use structures.

Comment: I think it was there to begin with, editted original question to reflect what I'm seeing before ANY modifications are performed.

Comment: We are seriously crossing streams here.Is the word this and the symbol  0 your weird characters? Looking at your xml I see a poorly structured xml, but I aren't seeing an invalid one, or any funny chars. If you want to see whether that piece of code should solve your problem, use a hex viewer and check the char ranges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of wasted time, the issue was simply Adobe InDesign producing a lot of weird characters into the exported XML - the ultimate solution ended up being altering an InDesign setting called:

```
Remap Break, Whitespace, and Special Characters
```

Which solved the XML issues instantly.