# wierd xml special character that can't parse using curl and SimpleXMLElement

Tags: php, xml, curl, simplexml

I'm downloading an xml file using curl and then parsing it using `simplexml_load_string()` and putting it to db.

I got a problem a that the file cannot be parse, its inside `<![CDATA[]]>` and i notice the file has some sort of a special character that i really dont know:

[special character](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1k8Na.png)

I'm getting the file like so:

```
$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
$contents = curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);
```

and i'm parsing it like so:

```
$gpx = simplexml_load_string($myfile,'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
```

The error that I got is this:

```
simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 7238: parser error : CData section not finished
```

How can i disregard those in to properly parse the xml file?

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Your XML is valid? Can you provide real XML url?

Comment: The xml does n t sound to be valid

Comment: You need to preprocess the XML string, good example of how to do that here: [How to skip invalid characters in XML file using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466035/how-to-skip-invalid-characters-in-xml-file-using-php)

Comment: fusion3k / cpugourou - It is a valid xml

Dan - Thanks for this I tried it and it works great will check and test this for multiple instances if ever there will be any other special char that has the same problem.